# sum of textbox and value in mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

can someone give me a hand on how will I be able to add the value in a textbox and existing data on my database and change the existing value in database to the sum of the value in textbox and database ?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. We will be glad to help you with specific problems you may have with **code you have written**.

Comment: I already did fix it hehe thanks tho.